# Cell tower information in range of device for android

Tags: android, mono, gsm

I want to create an application that is like the Open Signal app, but just the list of all GSM and WCDMA cell towers of a given network within range.
I can get one tower with its Cell ID and LAC.

I tried to get neighboring cell info, but it always returns a null value.

Also, can I get low level information like  BCCH and BCIS? Please help. :)

```
 GetSystemService(Context.TelephonyService);    
 GsmCellLocation cellLocation = (GsmCellLocation)telMag.CellLocation; 

 IList<NeighboringCellInfo> NeigboringList = telMag.NeighboringCellInfo;   

 foreach(NeighboringCellInfo u in NeigboringList)    
 {      
     gsm.Text += u.Cid.ToString() + " " + u.Lac.ToString() + " " + 
     u.Psc.ToString() + " " + u.Rssi.ToString() + " " + u.NetworkType.ToString();    
 }
```

Comment: Hello user2597863, can you please post the (small bit of) code where you call the neigbouring cell info function?    When you say, BCCH, do you mean the ARFCN?  What is the BCIS?

Comment: BSIC Base Station Identity Code, also known as “Color Code”
    TelephonyManager                         TelMag=TelephonyManager)GetSystemService(Context.TelephonyService);
            GsmCellLocation cellLocation = (GsmCellLocation)telMag.CellLocation;


            IList<NeighboringCellInfo> NeigboringList = telMag.NeighboringCellInfo;

         foreach(NeighboringCellInfo u in NeigboringList)
         {
            gsm.Text += u.Cid.ToString() + " " + u.Lac.ToString() + " " + u.Psc.ToString() + " " + u.Rssi.ToString() + " " + u.NetworkType.ToString() ;
         }

Comment: What do you get with getAllCellInfo()?

Comment: i reference this but in the FOR CONDITION for(int i = 0; i < NeighboringList.size(); i++) their is no NeigboringList.size() in the mono for android so icant get the same answer it had.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13208236/neighbouring-cell-information-is-inaccurate?rq=1

Comment: NeighboringList.size() equivalent for mono android is NeighboringList.Count(). But the count always return a null value. Do have any idea??

Comment: Read this question and answer, especially the 2nd answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16541172/getallcellinfo-returns-null-in-android-4-2-1.  And no, you can't get low level information.  Especially about BCIS, which does not exist.

Comment: No more way to retrieve those info?