# getNeighboringCellInfo() returning null

Tags: android, gsm

I'm  most of code used a little trying to get neighbor cells info (for the current cell info, everything works fine)

```
 List<NeighboringCellInfo> neighborCells = telMgr.getNeighboringCellInfo();
 if (neighborCells == null) {
     Log.d("cells", "Neighbor cells is null");
 } else {
     for (NeighboringCellInfo cell : neighborCells) {
         Log.d("cells", cell.getCid()+"-"+cell.getLac()+" "+(-113+cell.getRssi()*2)+"dB");

         String neighboringcell= cell.getCid()+"-"+cell.getLac()+" "+(-113+cell.getRssi()*2)+"dB";

         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), neighboringcell, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         mNeighboringcell.setText(neighboringcell);
     }
 }
```

i have used this code  and give this permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_UPDATES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

and i am tested Samsung 4.0  and lava 4.1

Please give me solution

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [android: NeighboringCellInfo always empty !? why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9328158/android-neighboringcellinfo-always-empty-why)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that's a bug, see this:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=24306

and this:

[Neighbouring cell information is inaccurate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13208236/neighbouring-cell-information-is-inaccurate?rq=1)